# How to read same file in multiple mocha test

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I am trying to read the same file in multiple mocha tests. Basically in test1,

```js
describe('test1', function() {
  var stream;
  before(function() {
    stream = fs.createReadStream('myfile.txt');
  });
  
  it ('should use this file to do something', function() {
    ...
  });
});
```

In test2.js, I also have similar lines of code.

```js
describe('test2', function() {
  var stream;
  before(function() {
    stream = fs.createReadStream('myfile.txt');
  });
  
  it ('should use this file to do something', function() {
    ...
  });
});
```

I can run either test separately, but not together. The error message I got is It gives me

"before all" hook
Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded

I read about asynchronous tests and tried a few things but none worked. How should this be done?

Comment: Just to verify: you really want to use a stream here? I'd guess you are not using it correctly.

Comment: I've copied your code into over here and I am unable to reproduce the issue you are reporting.

Comment: @FelixKling, yes the code is a parser that requires a stream as a parameter. Maybe that should be changed?